# OpenCV unproject 2D points to 3D with known depth `Z`

Tags: python, c++, opencv, projection, 3d-reconstruction

## Problem statement

I am trying to reproject 2D points to their original 3D coordinates, assuming I know the distance at which each point is. Following the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints), I managed to get it to work with zero-distortions. However, when there are distortions, the result is not correct.

## Current approach

So, the idea is to reverse the following:

[image: Distorted projection]

into the following:

[image]

By:

1. Geting rid of any distortions using `cv::undistortPoints`
2. Use intrinsics to get back to the normalized camera coordinates by reversing the second equation above
3. Multiplying by `z` to reverse the normalization.

## Questions

1. <s>Why do I need to subtract `f_x` and `f_y` to get back to the normalized camera coordinates (found empirically when testing)? In the code below, in step 2, if I don't subtract -- even the non-distorted result is off</s> This was my mistake -- I messed up the indexes.
2. If I include the distortion, the result is wrong -- what am I doing wrong?

## Sample code (C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <vector>

std::vector<cv::Point2d> Project(const std::vector<cv::Point3d>& points,
                                 const cv::Mat& intrinsic,
                                 const cv::Mat& distortion) {
  std::vector<cv::Point2d> result;
  if (!points.empty()) {
    cv::projectPoints(points, cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_64F, cvScalar(0.)),
                      cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_64F, cvScalar(0.)), intrinsic,
                      distortion, result);
  }
  return result;
}

std::vector<cv::Point3d> Unproject(const std::vector<cv::Point2d>& points,
                                   const std::vector<double>& Z,
                                   const cv::Mat& intrinsic,
                                   const cv::Mat& distortion) {
  double f_x = intrinsic.at<double>(0, 0);
  double f_y = intrinsic.at<double>(1, 1);
  double c_x = intrinsic.at<double>(0, 2);
  double c_y = intrinsic.at<double>(1, 2);
  // This was an error before:
  // double c_x = intrinsic.at<double>(0, 3);
  // double c_y = intrinsic.at<double>(1, 3);

  // Step 1. Undistort
  std::vector<cv::Point2d> points_undistorted;
  assert(Z.size() == 1 || Z.size() == points.size());
  if (!points.empty()) {
    cv::undistortPoints(points, points_undistorted, intrinsic,
                        distortion, cv::noArray(), intrinsic);
  }

  // Step 2. Reproject
  std::vector<cv::Point3d> result;
  result.reserve(points.size());
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < points_undistorted.size(); ++idx) {
    const double z = Z.size() == 1 ? Z[0] : Z[idx];
    result.push_back(
        cv::Point3d((points_undistorted[idx].x - c_x) / f_x * z,
                    (points_undistorted[idx].y - c_y) / f_y * z, z));
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  const double f_x = 1000.0;
  const double f_y = 1000.0;
  const double c_x = 1000.0;
  const double c_y = 1000.0;
  const cv::Mat intrinsic =
      (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << f_x, 0.0, c_x, 0.0, f_y, c_y, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  const cv::Mat distortion =
      // (cv::Mat_<double>(5, 1) << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  // This works!
      (cv::Mat_<double>(5, 1) << -0.32, 1.24, 0.0013, 0.0013);  // This doesn't!

  // Single point test.
  const cv::Point3d point_single(-10.0, 2.0, 12.0);
  const cv::Point2d point_single_projected = Project({point_single}, intrinsic,
                                                     distortion)[0];
  const cv::Point3d point_single_unprojected = Unproject({point_single_projected},
                                    {point_single.z}, intrinsic, distortion)[0];

  std::cout << "Expected Point: " << point_single.x;
  std::cout << " " << point_single.y;
  std::cout << " " << point_single.z << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Computed Point: " << point_single_unprojected.x;
  std::cout << " " << point_single_unprojected.y;
  std::cout << " " << point_single_unprojected.z << std::endl;
}
```

## Same Code (Python)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def Project(points, intrinsic, distortion):
  result = []
  rvec = tvec = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
  if len(points) > 0:
    result, _ = cv2.projectPoints(points, rvec, tvec,
                                  intrinsic, distortion)
  return np.squeeze(result, axis=1)

def Unproject(points, Z, intrinsic, distortion):
  f_x = intrinsic[0, 0]
  f_y = intrinsic[1, 1]
  c_x = intrinsic[0, 2]
  c_y = intrinsic[1, 2]
  # This was an error before
  # c_x = intrinsic[0, 3]
  # c_y = intrinsic[1, 3]

  # Step 1. Undistort.
  points_undistorted = np.array([])
  if len(points) > 0:
    points_undistorted = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(points, axis=1), intrinsic, distortion, P=intrinsic)
  points_undistorted = np.squeeze(points_undistorted, axis=1)

  # Step 2. Reproject.
  result = []
  for idx in range(points_undistorted.shape[0]):
    z = Z[0] if len(Z) == 1 else Z[idx]
    x = (points_undistorted[idx, 0] - c_x) / f_x * z
    y = (points_undistorted[idx, 1] - c_y) / f_y * z
    result.append([x, y, z])
  return result

f_x = 1000.
f_y = 1000.
c_x = 1000.
c_y = 1000.

intrinsic = np.array([
  [f_x, 0.0, c_x],
  [0.0, f_y, c_y],
  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
])

distortion = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])  # This works!
distortion = np.array([-0.32, 1.24, 0.0013, 0.0013])  # This doesn't!

point_single = np.array([[-10.0, 2.0, 12.0],])
point_single_projected = Project(point_single, intrinsic, distortion)
Z = np.array([point[2] for point in point_single])
point_single_unprojected = Unproject(point_single_projected,
                                     Z,
                                     intrinsic, distortion)
print "Expected point:", point_single[0]
print "Computed point:", point_single_unprojected[0]
```

The results for zero-distortion (as mentioned) are correct:

```
Expected Point: -10 2 12
Computed Point: -10 2 12
```

But when the distortions are included, the result is off:

```
Expected Point: -10 2 12
Computed Point: -4.26634 0.848872 12
```

### Update 1. Clarification

This is a camera to image projection -- I am assuming the 3D points are in the camera-frame coordinates.

### Update 2. Figured out the first question

OK, I figure out the subtraction of the `f_x` and `f_y` -- I was stupid enough to mess up the indexes. Updated the code to correct. The other question still holds.

### Update 3. Added Python equivalent code

To increase visibility, adding the Python codes, because it has the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to distort the points instead of undistort them? In theory if you have a 2D point it should already be undistorted... you have to go back on this part too. It should be the inverse of the x'' and y'' in your formula which is what undistort points actually does

Comment: @api55 This is all depends on computational efficiency tradeoffs: in an end-to-end solution, whenever you acquire an image, it is already distorted due to optics. Undistorting it means that you will call the undistortion routine on the whole image at every frame. However, if you go the other way, that is keep the frame distorted and distort sparse 3D points only when 3D-to-Image projection is required (or undistort sparse points only when reconstructing), you are saving a lot of computatio. But, if you are sure that you will require it anyway at every frame for all pixels -- it doesn't matter.

Comment: I follow your train of thought, but I thought you had the 2D points after the projection (and undistortion) and wanted to get it back... If you are using the distorted points directly, it makes sense to do as you said :) good that you found the answer to your question, but do not forget to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to Question 2

I found what the problem was -- **The 3D point coordinates matter**! I assumed that no matter what 3D coordinate points I choose, the reconstruction would take care of it. However, I noticed something strange: when using a range of 3D points, only a subset of those points were reconstructed correctly. After further investigation, I found out that only the images that are in the field of view of the camera would be properly reconstructed. The field-of-view is the function of the intrinsic parameters (and vice-versa).

For the above codes to work, try setting the parameters as follows (intrinsics are from my camera):

```
...
const double f_x = 2746.;
const double f_y = 2748.;
const double c_x = 991.;
const double c_y = 619.;
...
const cv::Point3d point_single(10.0, -2.0, 30.0);
...
```

Also, don't forget that in camera coordinates negative `y` coordinates is `UP` :)

## Answer to Question 1:

There was a bug where I was trying to access the intrinsics using

```
...
double f_x = intrinsic.at<double>(0, 0);
double f_y = intrinsic.at<double>(1, 1);
double c_x = intrinsic.at<double>(0, 3);
double c_y = intrinsic.at<double>(1, 3);
...
```

But `intrinsic` was a `3x3` matrix.

**Moral of the story**
Write unit tests!!!